# Unable to figure out filter in slickdb

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

Using scala with slickdb. I have table called persons. And I am filtering out persons by name as below

```
table.Persons.filter({ row => {
  println("inside filter")
  req.personName.map(name => row.personName === name).getOrElse(true:Rep[Boolean]) 
})
```

The table contains 3 rows. But still `println()` is executed only once. How is this filter working?

Comment: Do tables have a `withFilter` method. Try that instead and let us know if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you write something like

```
personTable.filter(p => { .... })
```

It evaluates it self as a `Query` which can generate the SQL Query when needed for actual DB querying. The generated SQL will be something like,

```
SELECT ...
FROM persons
WHERE ...
```

Now this SQL query is submitted to the DB for execution.

So, you code inside `{ ... }` gets evaluated to generate the Query itself. And it has no relation to how many rows do you have in your DB table.

So, the `println` in your example will run just once even if your DB table has 0 rows, 1 row or a million rows.